# What is the easiest way to generate a "Firebase ID token" (access token)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm looking for a way to easily generate the access token so that I can use in my REST client during the development. Preferably a way to generate through the terminal.

I've built an authorized https endpoint using this [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/authorized-https-endpoint). In order to make requests I have to send the access token in the Authorization header. Thing is that the access token expires every hour and I don't have a UI to log in and get a new access token.

Comment: I was building out a CLI application and had a similar problem. Firebase doesn't offer as robust tools in the Node version of their SDK. I ended up creating an API endpoint with a Cloud Functions and then just storing username/hash in a Firestore table and rolling my own auth. Sucked, but firebase-admin library is weak. Would love to see a better option!

Comment: Yeah, there should have a simple way for that. Imagine running the command `firebase auth --generate-token`, then passing user and password. It would be awesome! Maybe I'll write a script for that.

The best way I found so far was creating a simple website using the web SDK to authenticate the user and console.log the token. Too much work :/

Answer (score 0):

After I posted the question, I decided to write a very simple NodeJs script to generate the Firebase access token from `email` and `password`: [Firebase Auth Generate Token](https://github.com/tregismoreira/firebase-auth-generate-token).

### Getting Started

Clone the repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/tregismoreira/firebase-auth-generate-token.git
```

Install the dependencies.

```
# with Yarn
yarn

# or with NPM
npm install
```

Create a `.env` file in the root directory of your project and paste your Firebase credentials.

```
FIREBASE_API_KEY=
FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=
```

Start the script.

```
# with Yarn
yarn start

# or with NPM
npm run start
```

Once you run the script, you will be prompted the email and password. If the credentials are correct, the script will return the access token.

I hope you enjoy!